# Como manter uma lista com backgrounds alternados ao pesquisar

Tags: javascript, css, css3, tabela-html, background-color

Tenho uma lista com background cinza no item:nth-child(odd) porém quando faço uma pesquisa é inserido um display none nos itens que não contém nada relacionado e acaba bagunçando a ordem das cores, preciso que elas sejam reordenadas de acordo com o resultado da pesquisa

coloquei um exemplo do código no codepen:
https://codepen.io/renan-hugo/pen/aQVpdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que apenas com CSS não seja possível, já que o `even` e o `odd` irão também contar os elementos ocultos.

Uma solução é usar uma função para reaplicar os backgrounds, e chamá-la quando alterar o resultado da pesquisa:

```
function evenOdd(){
   // seleciona apenas as divs filhas diretas de .wrapper-assoc que não for oculta
   var linhas = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper-assoc > div:not([style*='display: none'])");
   var odd = "FFF";
   var even = "f30";
   for(var x=0; x < linhas.length; x++){
      if(x%2 != 0){
         linhas[x].style.background = "#"+even;
      }else{
         linhas[x].style.background = "#"+odd;
      }
   }
}
```

As linhas que não forem par recebem a cor do `even`, e as outras a cor do `odd`.

Pode usar um ternário se quiser em vez do `if`:

```
linhas[x].style.background = "#"+ (x%2 != 0 ? even : odd);
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function remover(){
   document.getElementById("linha3").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("linha6").style.display = "none";
   evenOdd();
}

function evenOdd(){
   var linhas = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper-assoc > div:not([style*='display: none'])");
   var odd = "FFF";
   var even = "f30";
   for(var x=0; x < linhas.length; x++){
      linhas[x].style.background = "#"+ (x%2 != 0 ? even : odd);
   }
}
```

```css
.wrapper-assoc > div:nth-child(even) {background: #f30}
.wrapper-assoc > div:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

```html
<button onclick="remover()">Ocultar linhas 3 e 6</button>
<div class="wrapper-assoc">
   <div>
      <div>1</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>2</div>
   </div>
   <div id="linha3">
      <div>3</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>4</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>5</div>
   </div>
   <div id="linha6">
      <div>6</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Fork do seu **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQeGWr)**

Compatibilidade da pseudo-classe de negação `:not()`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sam, uma ótima solução, porém já havia cogitado utilizar o seletor :not(), porém ao ver sua compatibilidade no caniuse se tornou inviável para o projeto...

Comment: Sei. Pode dizer o que o Caniuse acusou de incompatibilidade?

Comment: Exatamente, ele ainda não é bem suportado, https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot

Comment: Acho que vc está enganado. O seletor `:not()` com seletores CSS é amplamente compatível. Funciona inclusive no Safari para Windows descontinuado em 2012.

Comment: Mas existe outra forma de fazer a mesma coisa, basta selecionar todos os elementos sem o :not e verificar no laço se a div possui style="display: none;", mas nem vale a pena fazer isso já que o `:not([style*='display: none'])` é compatível com todos os navegadores, inclusive IE 9+.